# Django display ForeignKey field in Admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and Django(3) in which I have implemented a few models. One of them is `ReportsModel` which has `ForeignKey` field to other models. Now I want to display other model data in `ReportsModel` admin.

Here what I have tried so far:
**From `models.py`:**

```
class ReportsModel(models.Model):
    cdr_report = models.ForeignKey(CurrencyDistributionModel,
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None)
    cme_report = models.ForeignKey(CurrencyManagementExpenditureModel,
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None)
    cps_report = models.ForeignKey(CurrencyProcessingStorageModel,
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None)
    cma_report = models.ForeignKey(CurrencyManagementAssetsModel,
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.cdr_report is not None:
            return self.cdr_report.RequestId
        elif self.cme_report is not None:
            return self.cme_report.RequestId
        elif self.cps_report is not None:
            return self.cps_report.RequestId
        elif self.cma_report is not None:
            return self.cma_report.RequestId
```

To display the `ForeignKey` field in admin I'm using the `django_reverse_admin` package, here how I did that:
**From `admin.py`:**

```
class ReportAdmin(ReverseModelAdmin):
    report = None
    if ReportsModel.cdr_report is not None:
        report = 'cdr_report'
    elif ReportsModel.cme_report is not None:
        report = 'cme_report'
    elif ReportsModel.cps_report is not None:
        report = 'cps_report'
    elif ReportsModel.cma_report is not None:
        report = 'cma_report'
    search_fields = ['name']
    inline_reverse = [report]
    inline_type = 'stacked'


admin.site.register(ReportsModel, ReportAdmin)
```

now in the admin, it only works for the `cdr_report`, when I add a report of type `cme_report`, I'm getting the `RequestField` correctly, but the `cme_report` field is empty.

How can I display the `Inline Admin` on the base of condition?

Answer (score 1):

```
class ReportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display =  ("id", "someVariable" )

    def someVariable(self, obj):
        # do your logic, query or just return FK model data
        return obj.CurrencyDistributionModel.<WhateverIsYourField>


admin.site.register(ReportsModel, ReportAdmin):
```